# Library used to make CCleaner

Tags: c++

What kind of library has been used to make CCleaner?

Answer (score 5):

It is not open source, and it is not a .NET application, so we can't tell you.  I ran [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on it, and got no interesting information.  If there are any libraries involved, they are linked statically.

Check the website for the product, or ask the author:

http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner